# Nuxt.js Installation Errors

Tags: npm, installation, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I've tried to install a nuxt-app app a few times now. I've run it in my terminal with npm and yarn and as an administrator in the powershell. I continue to encounter errors in creating the app.

I've included the error log below for reference. I **think** that the **problem is with this throw error**: throw new SAOError(`Failed to install ${packageName} in ${cwd}`)

But I'm not sure. For reference, **the system I'm using is Windows 7**.

I've included photos of the error logs below:

- [Log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSE0l.png) The errors start about halfway through the log.
- [Log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWyb5.png)
- [Log3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYxEo.png)

Please and thank you.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 7):

Okey dokey. What ended up working for me was running the following code:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

as an administrator in the PowerShell.

This installed both Microsoft visual studio and Python 2.7. After executing the previously mentioned code, I ceased receiving errors for my nuxt.js app.

Comment: You can mark this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark below the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party.

Make sure you use LTS version node instead of current one.

Had the same issue with 16.4.0. After switching to 14.17.1, the installation works with no error.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems the installer expects to find a `python` executable and fails.

You need to [install python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) on your system, and make sure that it's accessible from the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot!