# Nuxt App Output Error when trying to Create

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to initialize a Nuxt Project using the command

**`yarn create nuxt-app <project-name>`**

i get this error:

```
C:\Users\AbdulAzeez\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\sao\lib\installPackages.js:108
        throw new SAOError(`Failed to install ${packageName} in ${cwd}`)
        ^

SAOError: Failed to install packages in C:\Users\AbdulAzeez\Desktop\vue-sax-demo
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AbdulAzeez\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\sao\lib\installPackages.js:108:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\AbdulAzeez\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\sao\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5) {
  __sao: true
}
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\AbdulAzeez\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin\create-nuxt-app
Arguments: vue-sax-demo
Directory: C:\Users\AbdulAzeez\Desktop
Output:
```

This is not the first time, i'm creating a nuxt-project, I'm just getting this Error recently!

I even tried using `npx`, the same `Error`

Comment: what is the version of `node` and `yarn` are you using?

Comment: have  you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533141/nuxt-js-installation-errors or this https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/441

Comment: ``yarn v1.22.4``
``Node v14.3.0``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the LTS version of node.js, the v14 is not stable. The current LTS version is 12.17.0 or see this link for the official LTS version if you are seen this in the future ( https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

after that run >>>

```
npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>
```

Comment: Not true anymore. The LTS version is now 14.15.4.

Comment: That is why he said., "see this link for the official LTS version if you are seen this in the future"